# Problema com acentuação em .js após concat e uglify no Gulp

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, gulp

Estou tentando otimizar o site do órgão onde trabalho e estou enfrentando problemas após concatenar e minificar os javascripts.

Nosso servidor Apache usa ISO-8859-1 e todos os meus arquivos no PHPStorm são configurados nesse mesmo charset.

Após fazer o concat e uglify no Gulp (que funcionou corretamente), tive problemas com acentuação em algumas funcionalidades do sistema, por exemplo o "DatePicker" do jQuery-ui.

Onde deveria estar escrito "**Horário**" está "**Hor?rio**".

Já tentei usar o "*gulp-convert-encoding*" e configurá-lo para ISO-8859-1, mas também não funcionou.

segue o trecho onde chamo os arquivos, os concateno e minifico:

```
var js  = [
    './msg/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js',
    './placeholder/jquery-placeholder.js',
    './msg/js/msg.js',
    './enviarArquivo/js/ajaxupload.3.5.js',
    './funcoes/funcoes.js',
    '../../../padroes/interface/scripts/shadowbox.js', // Padrão de interfaces
    './calendario/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js',
    './calendario/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js',
    './combobox/chosen.jquery.js',
];

gulp.task('minify-js', function () {
    gulp.src(js)
        .pipe(concat('script.min.js'))
        .pipe(convertEncoding({to: 'ISO-8859-1'}))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../pages/template/js/dist/'))
        .pipe(notify('Javascript compilado e minificado!'));
});
```

Vi que ao terminar de compilar, o arquivo *script.min.js* fica como UTF-8 e todos os caracteres acentuados são substituídos por (?).

Comment: Estava a ver no SOen uma sugestão de usar `stringfinal= decodeURIComponent(escape(stringinicial));`. Dá uma olhada caso resolva: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5396742/2256325. Dá uma olhada aqui também: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-utf8-convert

Comment: Olá, @Sergio. Muito Obrigado, mas não dá pra fazer dessa forma já que existem milhares de linhas de código para verificar. Outra coisa: qualquer alert que tentamos usar e que tenha acentuação também apresenta problema. Todos os arquivos estão em ISO-8859-1 e só depois de executar o Gulp o arquivo vira UTF-8.

Comment: E não podes converter o arquivo todo em string para UTF? Estás a abrir o arquivo em Node? ou a receber o conteúdo em string no node?

Comment: @Sergio, na verdade tentei converter o arquivo, mas o erro permanece. Não estou abrindo no Node. Estou visualizando direto pelo site, que está em PHP.

Comment: Cara pra mim você já identificou o problema, "_Todos os arquivos estão em ISO-8859-1_". Não pode converter os arquivos para UTF-8?

Comment: Tentou habilitar o [`ASCIIOnly`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#asciionly)?

Comment: @KaduAmaral, obrigado pela ajuda. Tentei agora habilitar o ASCIIOnly e também não funcionou. Sobre converter os arquivos em UTF8, não dá. Esses arquivos são usados em vários sistemas (na verdade não tenho como saber em quantos) de um órgão público estadual. Qualquer problema faz com que os contribuintes, auditores fiscais e contadores, congestionam o telefone. :(

Comment: Converti um dos arquivos para UT8 para testar e realmente funcionou. Usei o .pipe(convertEncoding({to: 'ISO-8859-1'})) e salvou o min.js como ISO. Vou procurar saber o que posso converter e tentar. Obrigado por enquanto.

Comment: @buback Já tentou converter para UTF-8 antes de concatenar e para ISO após ter concatenado?

Comment: O padrão para qualquer projeto é UTF-8, você não precisa utilizar o formato ISO-8859-1, por causa de acentuação, isso só força você a ter que converter caracteres para formatos especiais. o UTF-8 reconhece acentuação. Sem precisar de conversão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de várias tentativas, a única que funcionou foi convertendo cada arquivo para UTF8 antes de fazer o concat e o minify. Todas as acentuações funcionaram corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

if you use convertEncoding with from and to, all work fine:

```
 gulp.src('tmp/js/lib/**/*.js')
     //.pipe(stripCode({}))
     .pipe(convertEncoding({from: 'ISO-8859-15', to: 'UTF-8'}))
     .pipe(uglify())
     .pipe(convertEncoding({from: 'UTF-8', to: 'ISO-8859-15'}))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js/'));
```

Comment: It's StackOverflow in Portuguese, you must translate your answer.